# powershell - Grab specific info from array issue

Tags: powershell, remote-desktop

I have a small script that will help users in our environment shadow the sessions from other users in the facilities (I work at the corporate office, corporate users need the ability to shadow other user's sessions along different sites)

So I've got this:

```
$servers = "server1, server2, server3, server4, server5"

#search for user in servers farm
foreach ($server in $servers) { 

$results = & qwinsta.exe $userid /server:$server 

    if ($results -ne $null) {

        write-host "User found in $server"

        $serverfound = $server

        write-host $results[1]

        $sessionid = $results[1] | Where-Object { $_ -is 0..99}

        write-host "Session ID is: $sessionid"
    }
}
```

However, I can't get it to grab the session id from the result, this is the output of the script:

> Please wait while we search for x2adm on the RDSfarm Servers
>
> User found in server5
>
> rdp-tcp#0         x2adm                2  Active
>
> Session ID is:

I am trying to simply grab the number in the output and assign it to $sessionid so that I can fully automate the shadowing process.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a good answer here to help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23445175/qwinsta-serversomesrv-equivalent-in-powershell

Comment: I think your problem is with $servers = "server1, server2, server3, server4, server5". Should be $servers = "server1", "server2", "server3", "server4", "server5" so you get an array with 5 elements.

Comment: I agree with Dan, you just passed it a string and not 5 individual items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you use `ConvertFrom-String` instead.  It's awesome for parsing data like this.

```
ConvertFrom-String $results[1]

P1 : 
P2 : console
P3 : Stephen
P4 : 1
P5 : Active
P6 :
```

So our `$SessionID` value would be found in p4 (P# is just an arbitrary name that this cmdlet gives to the strings it finds).

The full command would be

```
$sessionID = convertfrom-string $results[1] | select -expand P4
```

This will work with your current code with no further modifications.

Comment: I forgot about ConvertFrom-String. So used to using ConvertFrom-StringData

Comment: I am sorry for my delay work got really busy this past few weeks, this solution worked this is exactly what i needed to finish the automation. I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Check the data type of `$servers` and you will see that it is a string and not a string array which is how you are treating it.

```
PS C:\Users\matt> $servers = "server1, server2, server3, server4, server5"
PS C:\Users\matt> $servers.GetType().FullName

System.String
```

You can read more about the basic concepts of arrays from [about_arrays](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847882.aspx) You need to define it like this.

```
$servers = "server1", "server2", "server3", "server4", "server5"
```

---

As far as dealing with output from qwinsta [I have an answer that converts data from that into a PowerShell object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29130697/3829407). Might not need to be that extreme since you are not using the exact same command that the Op of the linked question was. Point being is that `ConvertFrom-StringData` is a powerful cmdlet.

Comment: It returns an array when the username starts with a number, this is the last problem i am having with it i can't seem to be able to convert it to a string, i tried:

[string[]]$results = & qwinsta.exe "$userid" /server:$server

[string]$results = & qwinsta.exe "$userid" /server:$server 

$results -join ' '

And the type either comes back array or object, how can i make it return a string regardless ?