# Extracting RDP SessionID from qwinsta

Tags: windows, powershell, remote-desktop, rdp

I'm attempting to extract the session ID from the qwinsta command, as I need to use that ID to actually terminate an RDP session using powershell.  Apologies, as I'm not extremely proficient with powershell, and am fairly unfamiliar with the environment.

```
qwinsta /server:$hostname
SESSIONNAME  USERNAME        ID    STATE    TYPE      DEVICE
services                      0    Disc                    
console                       1    Conn  
rdp-tcp#0    $username       10    Active   rdpwd    
rdp-tcp                   65536    Listen
```

What I would like to do is pull ONLY the ID from the row rdp-tcp#0, to use in a powershell script that will automatically identify the proper ID from the RDP session, and then I can use it in my logoff command in my script to disconnect from the remote host:

logoff /server:$hostname $sessionID

Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23445175/qwinsta-serversomesrv-equivalent-in-powershell   Similar question here, can you see if there is a usable answer there? (The selected answer even has a function written to do what you want in powershell, making it easy for you to use the return value)

Comment: Kage, that doesn't quite work, as it leaves in the heading and '----' for each category, but its put me on the right track.  Thanks.

Comment: Change the regular expression from my answer to the other question to `'rdp-tcp#0.*(\d+)\s+Active'` if you need to explicitly match the session `rdp-tcp#0`.