# How do I log off all currently logged on users?

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, gpo

I would like to create a GPO that includes a scheduled task, that should be run once every day. The scheduled task should get a list of all users currently logged on a specific workstation and log them off (just lock Windows would be prefered, but a regular log off seems easier to make)

First I tried to execute the following with the scheduled task:
"shutdown.exe /f /l" to log off users. But the command was being executed by the SYSTEM user, so all regular users was not being logged off.

2nd idea was then to create a Powershell Script and place on each workstation. The script should be able to extract all currently logged on users on the workstation and log off / lock screen for all users.

```
$Sessions = quser

# Parse the session IDs from the output
$SessionIds = ($Sessions -split ' +')[3]
$SessionIds

# Loop through each session ID and pass each to the logoff command
ForEach-Object ($SessionId in $SessionIds){
    logoff $SessionId
    }
```

Comment: what is exactly your question? Does the script not work?

Comment: This may be of some help for you https://4sysops.com/archives/log-off-multiple-users-on-a-schedule-with-powershell/

Comment: My question is how to create a script, that can get all users currently logged on and then log them off (or just lock-screen).
The script does not currently work, as the $SessionIds only captures the "ID" of the quser, but not the actual value for each logged on users.

Comment: get the active sessions using `qwinsta` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23445175/qwinsta-serversomesrv-equivalent-in-powershell) and then remove them using `rwinsta` (https://ss64.com/nt/reset-session.html)

Answer (score 2):

Neither of the above solutions worked for me for all cases because of the variation in blank fields and time formatting.  The following worked better.

```
$first = 1
quser | ForEach-Object {
    if ($first -eq 1) {
        $userPos = $_.IndexOf("USERNAME")
        $sessionPos = $_.IndexOf("SESSIONNAME")
        $idPos = $_.IndexOf("ID")
        $statePos = $_.IndexOf("STATE")
        $first = 0
    }
    else {
        $user = $_.substring($userPos,$sessionPos-$userPos).Trim()
        $session = $_.substring($sessionPos,$idPos-$sessionPos).Trim()
        $id = $_.substring($idPos,$statePos-$idPos).Trim()
        Write-Output "Logging off user:$user session:$session id:$id"
        logoff $id
    }
}
```

Comment: Nicely done.  Unfortunately ID is right justified, so if it's 3 digits, the first digit will appear to the left of the header above it.  This is useful for me in parsing quser output into objects.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `($Sessions -split ' +')[3]` gives you the 4th element out of *all* elements produced by the split. What you actually want is the 4th element from *each split line*. Also, you should index from the end of the line, because otherwise you'd miss disconnected sessions, as those don't have a session name:

```
PS C:\> quser
 USERNAME              SESSIONNAME        ID  STATE   IDLE TIME  LOGON TIME
 foo                                       7  Disc         1:23  23.10.2019 09:12
>bar                   rdp-tcp#114        12  Active          .  23.10.2019 10:12
 baz                   rdp-tcp#112        13  Active          .  23.10.2019 10:13
```

Something like this should work:

```
quser | Select-Object -Skip 1 | ForEach-Object {
    $id = ($_ -split ' +')[-5]
    logoff $id
}
```

You could also use `qwinsta` instead of `quser`, but then you should filter out the listener as well as the "services" (and maybe the "console") session before terminating sessions.

Answer (score 1):

Might as well turn this into a parser.

```
# q.ps1

$first = 1
quser 2>$null | ForEach-Object {
    if ($first -eq 1) {
        $userPos = $_.IndexOf("USERNAME")
        $sessionPos = $_.IndexOf("SESSIONNAME")
        $idPos = $_.IndexOf("ID") - 2   # ID is right justified
        $statePos = $_.IndexOf("STATE")
        $idlePos = $_.IndexOf("IDLE TIME")
        $logonPos = $_.IndexOf("LOGON TIME")
        $first = 0
    }
    else {
        $user = $_.substring($userPos,$sessionPos-$userPos).Trim()
        $session = $_.substring($sessionPos,$idPos-$sessionPos).Trim()
        $id = [int]$_.substring($idPos,$statePos-$idPos).Trim()
        $state = $_.substring($statePos,$idlePos-$statePos).Trim()
        $idle = $_.substring($idlePos,$logonPos-$idlePos).Trim()
        $logon = [datetime]$_.substring($logonPos,$_.length-$logonPos).Trim()
        [pscustomobject]@{User = $user; Session = $session; ID = $id; 
            State = $state; Idle = $idle; Logon = $logon}
    }
}
```

```
.\q | ft

User  Session  ID State  Idle Logon
----  -------  -- -----  ---- -----
admin console 111 Active none 2/6/2022 11:21:00 PM
```

```
.\q | % { logoff $_.id }
```

Comment: Running in UK locale this has datetime conversion issues.
`Cannot convert value "25/04/2023 15:05" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."`

Comment: This seems to do the trick: `$logon = [datetime]::Parse($_.substring($logonPos, $_.length - $logonPos).Trim(), [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture) # Parse the date using the system locale`

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the `-5` to `-6` based on [@AnsgarWiecher's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58519557/584676) for Windows 10.

```
quser | Select-Object -Skip 1 | ForEach-Object {
    $id = ($_ -split ' +')[-6]
    logoff $id
}
```

Thank you Ansgar.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31921799)