# Get name of logged user in Local Network using Python

Tags: python, powershell, cmd

I am writing Python code to get the username of logged user from another computer in a local network. The request works separately both in the command line and in the powershell. However, when I try to enter a request through the  subprocess in Python, an error occurs. Tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
import subprocess, sys

p = subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe",
              "query session /server:com190"],
              stdout=sys.stdout)
p.communicate()
```

Result:

*query : The term 'query' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, s
cript file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path w
as included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- query session /server:com190
- CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (query:String) [], CommandNotFou
  ndException
- FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException*

Commands like ipconfig and ping works perfect in the code.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: I don't use Windows but if you normally execute it in one line `powershell.exe query session /server:com190` then you need list `["powershell.exe", "query", "session", "/server:com190"]` . But if normally you first start `powershell.exe` and later you type `query session /server:com190` then in `Popen` you have to use `["powershell.exe"]` and later use `p.` to send `query session /server:com190`

Comment: What is the need to use `powershell` to run a plain .exe command? If PowerShell can be used, then https://stackoverflow.com/a/23454741/447901

Comment: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-Terminal-Server-3fadaa68

Comment: Does this answer your question? [qwinsta /server:somesrv equivalent in Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23445175/qwinsta-serversomesrv-equivalent-in-powershell)